# Get data from column with JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a SQL-server, in one table some data are stored as a JSON object.

| ID | Date | Customer details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | {'Country':167,'AccountNumber':'123456','SwiftBic':'ABC123'} |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | {'Country':666,'AccountNumber':'765432','SwiftBic':'XYZ123'} |

How do "split" this info into separate columns like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1egI.png)

| ID | Date | Country | AccountNumber | SwiftBic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 167 | 123456 | ABC123 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 666 | 765432 | XYZ123 |

Comment: Which database system are you using? Is it Microsoft SQL Server or something else?

Comment: Yes, unsure about the version, but i think it's 2019

Comment: You can use [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this :

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Details, 
    JSON_VALUE(details,'$.Country') AS Country,
    JSON_VALUE(details,'$.AccountNumber') AS AccountNumber,
    JSON_VALUE(details,'$.SwiftBic') AS SwiftBic
FROM ThatTable
```

If you need to use these columns frequently, especially if you need to use them in `WHERE` clauses, you can create computed columns using `JSON_VALUE` and index them:

```
CREATE TABLE ThatTable (
   ...
   Country AS JSON_VALUE(CustomerDetails, '$.Country') PERSISTED,
   ...
)

CREATE INDEX IX_ThatTable_Country ON dbo.ThatTable(Country);
```

It's not possible to expand arbitrary properties to columns. The columns in a query are similar to types in a strongly typed language and have to be known in advance.

**Single or Double quotes?**

The [JSON Standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#page-9) specifies that only double-quotes can be used as quotation marks in JSON.

```
  quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
```

Parsers and serializers *must* use and understand `"` as a quotation mark but are free to reject `'`. Using `'` can lead to problems.

T-SQL is strict about this, so the following is invalid :

```
{'Country':167,'AccountNumber':'123456','SwiftBic':'ABC123'}
```

While this is valid:

```
{"Country":167,"AccountNumber":"123456","SwiftBic":"ABC123"}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but got the error code: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found at position 1.

To me it looks like JSON but i guess it's not?

Comment: @EmeliaJohansson In the JSON standard only double quotes can be used to delimit text. SQL Server follows this strictly. You'll have to use `REPLACE(field,'''','"')` to replace single with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which is easier if you have many properties to pull out, is to use `OPENJSON`

```sql
SELECT 
    t.ID,
    t.Date,
    j.*
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(t.details)
  WITH (
    Country varchar(30),
    AccountNumber varchar(10),
    SwiftBic varchar(30)
  ) j;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3421739a99328b569de52839a35b3838)

As mentioned, single-quotes are not valid as JSON delimiters, so you need to fix that up.